# Raft and objects are white

Tags: steam, linux, raft

I just installed Raft, and all the objects in the game appear white.

Specs:

- Acer Nitro 5
- Ubuntu 20.10
- graphics card: NVIDIA GeFORCE 1650
- driver: nvidia-driver-455
- `PROTON_USE_WINED3D=1 %command%` launch option

Is there an issue with the Proton runtime? Or what could be the problem? On protondb.com, there are lots of reviews saying that the game works flawlessly on Linux.

[image: in-game screenshot] [image: starting screen]

Comment: Have you tried DXVK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem...

...simply by removing the line `PROTON_USE_WINED3D=1 %command%` from the launch options.

I thought it was required, given that a Linux guide recommended this option for the game Among Us.

Comment: i have this problem too, how did you change that line?